# Can a point in a separable metric space lie in the closure of infinitely many disjoint open sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable metric space and $\{U_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ a countable family of open subsets of $X$. Let $x\in X$ such that $x\in\overline U_i\setminus U_i$ for all $i\ge 1$. Is it possible that the sets $U_i$ are pairwise disjoint?

Comment: Yes. Try a countably infinite set of sectors with the origin as a vertex.

Comment: Consider an infinite sequence of disjoint open intervals converging to $0$, say $(\frac12,1)$, $(\frac13,\frac12)$, $(\frac14,\frac13)$, . . . Partition this sequence into infinitely many disjoint subsequences. The union of each of those subsequences is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ having $0$ in its closure.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Nice examples.